# delete duplicate entries in table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-delete

I want to delete multiple duplicate keys from the below table:

```
id | name   | uid
1  | ekta   | 5
2  | ekta   | 5
3  | sharma | 10
4  | sharma | 10
```

want it to be like

```
id | name   | uid
1  | ekta   | 5
3  | sharma | 10
```

I am using mysql. Is it ossible.?
I can't use  `unique constraint` query to make unique enteries because i want this duplicate entries ones entered to the table.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of doing this is by joining the table on a subquery using `LEFT JOIN`. The subquery gets the lowest `ID` for every `UID`. When a record doesn't have match on the subquery, it just means that it has no matching record and can be safely deleted.

```
DELETE  a
FROM    TableName a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  uid, MIN(ID) min_ID
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY uid
        ) b ON  a.uid = b.uid AND
                a.ID = b.min_ID
WHERE   b.uid IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a186c/1)

However, if the records of `UID` can have different name, then you need to include `name` on the `group by` clause or else only unique `uid` with the lowest `ID` will remain.

```
DELETE  a
FROM    TableName a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  uid, MIN(ID) min_ID, name
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY uid, name
        ) b ON  a.uid = b.uid AND
                a.ID = b.min_ID AND
                a.name = b.name
WHERE   b.uid IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0ffb/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*the same uid with different name*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c460c/1)

Comment: i have to fine same name and uid and then have to delete duplicate record so its bit complicated. :(

Comment: it's not complicated, execute the first delete statement.

Comment: 2nd one is working as i need..thnks so much..!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  DELETE DupRows.*
  FROM MyTable AS DupRows
  INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MIN(ID) AS minId, col1, col2
            FROM MyTable
            GROUP BY col1, col2
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
             ) AS SaveRows 
  ON SaveRows.col1 = DupRows.col1 AND SaveRows.col2 = DupRows.col2
  AND SaveRows.minId <> DupRows.ID;
```