# Delete Duplicate Fingerprint entries

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I would like to ask how can I delete duplicate records in MySQL from my fingerprint table.

I need to delete any record if found the same **created_date** AND **created_time** AND **employee_number**

Thanks,
Jassim

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete duplicate entries in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516367/delete-duplicate-entries-in-table)

Comment: Removed `psql` tag. `psql` is the PostgreSQL command-line client, and there's no sign this question has anything to do with it

Answer (score 2):

If you have auto increment key then,

```
DELETE f1 FROM fingerprint f1, fingerprint f2 WHERE f1.autoincreament < f2.autoincreament AND f1.created_date = f2.created_date AND f1.created_time = f2.created_time AND f1.employee_number = f2.employee_number
```

Refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)